# post parameter in nodejs is null

Tags: node.js, postman

In my first test node application post parameters are null.

my code at controll.js:

```
var db = require('../database');
exports.save_visitor = function (req,res) {
    console.log("I am here ");
    console.log(req.params);
    var name = req.param('name');
    name = req.params;
    console.log(name);
    res.send('I am from post');
}
```

and at app.js:

```
// ...
app.post('/visitor', controller.save_visitor);
// ...
```

In console I am getting:

```
I am here 
[]
null
```

What is wrong?

I am using Chrome's extension [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) to send post request
and I am adding `name` as `key` and `some text` as `value`.

Comment: `req.params` doesn't contain body properties, it contains [routing properties](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params). You should use [req.body](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.body) instead.

Comment: I tried that also it prints {} on console @robertklep

Comment: @SharanabasuAngadi have you installed the `body-parser` middleware?

Comment: yup @robertklep my package.json is as {
  "name": "my_express",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "express": "3.12.0",
    "jade": "~1.9.2",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "mysql": "^2.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0"
  }
}

Comment: @SharanabasuAngadi and are you actually adding it to your Express app? If so, how? Can you edit your post and show how you set up your app.

Comment: are you sending file in form data? and also let me know that are you trying with express for routing?

Comment: @Dineshws Finally fixed the issue , it was problem with express. I was using express 4. I deleted node_module and installed express 3 . its working fine.